# Dynamo DB Local - Connection Refused

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to connect to Local Dynamo DB using the AWS Java SDK. So I installed the Local Dynamo DB and started the javascript shell. All works fine and the shell starts at the usual address `http://localhost:8000/shell/`

Now when I try to access the Dynamo DB Instance via the AWS SDK things start to break.

Here is my code:

```java
public class MyDynamoDB {
    private AmazonDynamoDBClient client;

    public MyDynamoDB() {
        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
        client.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8000");
    }

    public void saveAndLoad() {
        DynamoDBMapperConfig config = new DynamoDBMapperConfig(new TableNameOverride("xyz"));
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client, config);
        Data data = new Data();
        ...
        mapper.save(data);


        //check if persisted
        Data d = mapper.load(Data.class, "Key");
        if (d != null) {
            System.out.println(" Found data: " + d.getStuff());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data not found");
        }
    }
}
```

On running this I am getting the following stack trace

```
Nov 19, 2015 4:00:47 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
```

Comment: How are you starting DynamoDBLocal? Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem starting DynamoDb via Maven.  Adding a / to the endpoint didn't help.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mark I did not get time to continue on the same. I see Dani has posted an answer, let me know if that works... I'll retry in a couple of days and post an answer if something works.

Comment: @AgentX I tried Dani's suggestion but sadly it didn't work.  If you do get something, I'd be interested.

Comment: @mark I know its late but can you try my answer?

Comment: in my case docker failed to create the database, when queried immediately after creation of the vm it seemed to be running but 1 second later it went down, I found the reasons using `docker logs <container-id>`

Answer (score 15):

You need to trigger DynamoDB in command prompt..

Go the location where the Dynamodb cli is installed and run the following command

java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb

verify if it is running by http://localhost:8000/shell/

Answer (score 7):

If you are using SAM-LOCAL or developing aws lambda function using eclipse this answer can be useful.

Short Answer **assign an IP alias to loopback to reach out using a different address to 127.0.0.1, and update the endpoint to that address**

From the command line run

`ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.123.1`

And from lambda code instead of accessing http://localhost:8000/ use http://172.16.123.1:8000/

refer to this [link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/issues/102#issuecomment-326177151) for explanation.

Long Answer

In lambda function pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.313</version>
</dependency>
```

started dynomodb using

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

do IP alias

```
ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.123.1
```

For accessing DynmoDb from Code do

```
DynamoDB dynamoDb = new DynamoDB(AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()).withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://172.16.123.1:8000/", "local")).build());
```

After you are done with testing lambda function do

```
ifconfig lo0 -alias 172.16.123.1
```

Answer (score 5):

Just fought with the same issue - append a slash to the endpoint url solved it for me.

```
client.setEndpoint( "http://localhost:8000/");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SAM-LOCAL, you can't access localhost:8080 directly.

I've found 2 options:

**OPTION 1**

Instead of calling *http://localhost:8080* , you must use your machine's IP *http://192.168.xx.xxx:8000*

**OPTION 2**

Create a network on DynamoDB Docker container.  You can find different ways to do that here: [connecting AWS SAM Local with dynamodb in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926260/connecting-aws-sam-local-with-dynamodb-in-docker)

My favorite: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309422/13035616

Answer (score 0):

I recently face this problem. The solution for me was to change the dynamodb endpoint to: **http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000**

```
new DocumentClient({
  endpoint: "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000",
  sslEnabled: false,
  region: 'eu-central-1', // change to your region
  accessKeyId: 'keyid123',
  secretAccessKey: 'secret123',
})
```