# connecting AWS SAM Local with dynamodb in docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sam-cli

I've set up an api gateway/aws lambda pair using AWS sam local and confirmed I can call it successfully after running

`sam local start-api`

I've then added a local dynamodb instance in a docker container and created a table on it using the aws cli

But, having added the code to the lambda to write to the dynamodb instance I receive:

> 2018-02-22T11:13:16.172Z  ed9ab38e-fb54-18a4-0852-db7e5b56c8cd    error:
>   could not write to table: {"message":"connect ECONNREFUSED
>   0.0.0.0:8000","code":"NetworkingError","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"0.0.0.0","port":8000,"region":"eu-west-2","hostname":"0.0.0.0","retryable":true,"time":"2018-02-22T11:13:16.165Z"}
>   writing event from command:
>   {"name":"test","geolocation":"xyz","type":"createDestination"} END
>   RequestId: ed9ab38e-fb54-18a4-0852-db7e5b56c8cd

I saw online that you might need to connect to the same docker network so I created a network `docker network create lambda-local` and have changed my start commands to:

`sam local start-api --docker-network lambda-local`

and

`docker run -v "$PWD":/dynamodb_local_db -p 8000:8000 --network=lambda-local  cnadiminti/dynamodb-local:latest`

but still receive the same error

sam local is printing out `2018/02/22 11:12:51 Connecting container 98b19370ab92f3378ce380e9c840177905a49fc986597fef9ef589e624b4eac3 to network lambda-local`

I'm creating the dynamodbclient using:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const dynamodbURL = process.env.dynamodbURL || 'http://0.0.0.0:8000'
const awsAccessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID || '1234567'
const awsAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY || '7654321'
const awsRegion = process.env.AWS_REGION || 'eu-west-2'

console.log(awsRegion, 'initialising dynamodb in region: ')

let dynamoDbClient
const makeClient = () => {
  dynamoDbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    endpoint: dynamodbURL,
    accessKeyId: awsAccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: awsAccessKey,
    region: awsRegion
  })
  return dynamoDbClient
}

module.exports = {
  connect: () => dynamoDbClient || makeClient()
}
```

and inspecting the dynamodbclient my code is creating shows

```
DocumentClient {
  options:
   { endpoint: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000',
     accessKeyId: 'my-key',
     secretAccessKey: 'my-secret',
     region: 'eu-west-2',
     attrValue: 'S8' },
  service:
   Service {
     config:
      Config {
        credentials: [Object],
        credentialProvider: [Object],
        region: 'eu-west-2',
        logger: null,
        apiVersions: {},
        apiVersion: null,
        endpoint: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000',
        httpOptions: [Object],
        maxRetries: undefined,
        maxRedirects: 10,
        paramValidation: true,
        sslEnabled: true,
        s3ForcePathStyle: false,
        s3BucketEndpoint: false,
        s3DisableBodySigning: true,
        computeChecksums: true,
        convertResponseTypes: true,
        correctClockSkew: false,
        customUserAgent: null,
        dynamoDbCrc32: true,
        systemClockOffset: 0,
        signatureVersion: null,
        signatureCache: true,
        retryDelayOptions: {},
        useAccelerateEndpoint: false,
        accessKeyId: 'my-key',
        secretAccessKey: 'my-secret' },
     endpoint:
      Endpoint {
        protocol: 'http:',
        host: '0.0.0.0:8000',
        port: 8000,
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        pathname: '/',
        path: '/',
        href: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/' },
     _clientId: 1 },
  attrValue: 'S8' }
```

Should this setup work? How do I get them talking to each other?

---- edit ----

Based on a twitter conversation it's worth mentioning (maybe) that I can interact with dynamodb at the CLI and in the web shell

[image: dynamo db at the CLI]

[image: dynamodb web shell]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Many thanks to [Heitor Lessa who answered me on Twitter](https://twitter.com/heitor_lessa/status/968574144681037826) with an example repo

Which pointed me at the answer...

- dynamodb's docker container is on 127.0.0.1 from the context of my
  machine (which is why I could interact with it)
- SAM local's docker container is on 127.0.0.1 from the context of my
  machine
- But they aren't on 127.0.0.1 from each other's context

So: https://github.com/heitorlessa/sam-local-python-hot-reloading/blob/master/users/users.py#L14

Pointed me at changing my connection code to:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const awsRegion = process.env.AWS_REGION || 'eu-west-2'

let dynamoDbClient
const makeClient = () => {
  const options = {
    region: awsRegion
  }
  if(process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
    options.endpoint = 'http://dynamodb:8000'
  }
  dynamoDbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(options)
  return dynamoDbClient
}

module.exports = {
  connect: () => dynamoDbClient || makeClient()
}
```

with the important lines being:

```
if(process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
  options.endpoint = 'http://dynamodb:8000'
}
```

**from the context of the SAM local docker container the dynamodb container is exposed via its name**

My two startup commands ended up as:

`docker run -d -v "$PWD":/dynamodb_local_db -p 8000:8000 --network lambda-local --name dynamodb cnadiminti/dynamodb-local`

and

`AWS_REGION=eu-west-2 sam local start-api --docker-network lambda-local`

with the only change here being to give the dynamodb container a name

Comment: Small addition for anyone caught out - you need to specifically create the `lambda-local` network beforehand: `docker network create lambda-local`

Comment: Someone can clarify why the sam local container cannot communicate via default bridge with the dynamodb container?

Comment: But... now you can't interact with the dynamodb shell

Answer (score 35):

If your using sam-local on a mac like alot of devs you should be able to just use

`options.endpoint = "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000"`

Or on newer installs of docker https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-18030-ce-mac59-2018-03-26

`options.endpoint = "http://host.docker.internal:8000"`

Instead of having to do multiple commands like Paul showed above (but that might be more platform agnostic?).

Comment: This fixed my problem on Mac

Comment: I was struggling for long time  as I was having "http://localhost:8000"  instead of. "http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000" for local dynamoDB endpoint. This was a lifesaver.

Comment: This works for PostgreSQL with connection string = `postgres://postgres:mysecurepassword@docker.for.mac.localhost:5432/mydb?ssl=false`

Answer (score 15):

The other answers were too overly complicated / unclear for me.  Here is what I came up with.

## Step 1: use docker-compose to get DynamoDB local running on a custom network

**docker-compose.yml**

**Note** the network name `abp-sam-backend`, service name `dynamo` and that `dynamo` service is using the `backend` network.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  dynamo:
    container_name: abp-sam-nestjs-dynamodb
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - dynamodata:/home/dynamodblocal
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
    command: '-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath .'

networks:
  backend:
    name: abp-sam-backend

volumes:
  dynamodata: {}
```

Start DyanmoDB local container via:

`docker-compose up -d dynamo`

## Step 2: Write your code to handle local DynamoDB endpoint

```js
import { DynamoDB, Endpoint } from 'aws-sdk';

const ddb = new DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

if (process.env['AWS_SAM_LOCAL']) {
  ddb.endpoint = new Endpoint('http://dynamo:8000');
} else if ('local' == process.env['APP_STAGE']) {
  // Use this when running code directly via node. Much faster iterations than using sam local
  ddb.endpoint = new Endpoint('http://localhost:8000');
}
```

**Note** that I'm using the hostname alias `dynamo`.  This alias is auto-created for me by docker inside the `abp-sam-backend` network.  The alias name is just the service name.

## Step 3: Launch the code via `sam local`

```
sam local start-api -t sam-template.yml --docker-network abp-sam-backend --skip-pull-image --profile default --parameter-overrides 'ParameterKey=StageName,ParameterValue=local ParameterKey=DDBTableName,ParameterValue=local-SingleTable'
```

**Note** that I'm telling `sam local` to use the existing network `abp-sam-backend` that was defined in my `docker-compose.yml`

## End-to-end example

I made a working example (plus a bunch of other features) that can be found at https://github.com/rynop/abp-sam-nestjs

Answer (score 9):

`SAM` starts a docker container `lambci/lambda` under the hood, if you have another container hosting `dynamodb` for example or any other services to which you want to connect your lambda, so you should have both in the **same network**

Suppose dynamodb (notice `--name`, this is the endpoint now)

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name DynamoDBEndpoint amazon/dynamodb-local
```

This will result in something like this

```
0e35b1c90cf0....
```

To know which network this was created inside:

```
docker inspect 0e35b1c90cf0
```

It should give you something like

```
...
Networks: {
     "services_default": {//this is the <<myNetworkName>>

....
```

If you know your networks and want to put docker container inside specific network, you can save the above steps and do this in one command while starting container using `--network` option

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --network myNetworkName --name DynamoDBEndpoint amazon/dynamodb-local
```

**Important:** Your lambda code now should have endpoint to dynamo to `DynamoDBEndpoint`

To say for example:

```
if(process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
  options.endpoint = 'http://DynamoDBEndpoint:8000'
}
```

Testing everything out:

**Using `lambci:lambda`**

This should only list all tables inside your other dynamodb container

```
docker run -ti --rm --network myNetworkName lambci/lambda:build-go1.x \
   aws configure set aws_access_key_id "xxx" && \
   aws configure set aws_secret_access_key "yyy" &&  \
   aws --endpoint-url=http://DynamoDBEndpoint:4569 --region=us-east-1 dynamodb list-tables
```

Or to invoke a function: (Go Example, same as NodeJS)

```
#Golang
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:go1.x handlerName '{"some": "event"}'
#Same for NodeJS 
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:nodejs10.x index.handler
```

More Info about lambci/lambda can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/)

**Using `SAM` (which uses the same container `lmabci/lambda`):**

```
sam local invoke --event myEventData.json --docker-network myNetworkName MyFuncName
```

You can always use `--debug` option in case you want to see more details.

**Alternatively**, You can also use `http://host.docker.internal:8000` without the hassle of playing with docker, this URL is reserved internally and gives you an access to your host machine but make sure you expose port 8000 when you start dynamodb container. Although it is quite easy but it doesn't work in all operating systems. For more details about this feature, please check [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)

Comment: I am facing an error like host.docker.internal\'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1\' .  I am running Docker Toolbox . Should this work ?

Comment: `http://host.docker.internal:8000` doesn't work, even with `docker run -p 8000:8000 ....`

Comment: Amazingly insightful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As @Paul mentioned, it is about configuring your network between the docker containers - lambda and database.

Another approach that worked for me (using docker-compose).

docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  db:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - my_network
    environment:
      ...
    volumes:
      ...

networks:
  my_network:
```

Then, after `docker-compose up`, running `docker network ls` will show:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                        DRIVER              SCOPE
7eb440d5c0e6        dev_my_network              bridge              local
```

My docker container name is `dev_db_1`.

My js code is:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "dev_db_1",
    port: 3306,
    ...
});
```

Then, running the `sam` command:

```
sam local invoke --docker-network dev_my_network -e my.json
```

Stack:

- Docker: 18.03.1-ce
- Docker-compose: 1.21.1
- MacOS HighSierra 10.13.6

Comment: is it possible to spin up the sam local container (i.e. with `start-api` cmd) from within `docker-compose`? As opposed to separately via manual command from cli?

Comment: @Kwhitejr as mentioned in his blog @ https://pauldambra.github.io/2018/02/serverless-3.html, you need run command with docker-network parameter e.g. sam local start-api --docker-network lambda-local

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to run DynamoDB, I believe the correct command to use the LocalStack network for SAM is:

```sh
sam local start-api --env-vars env.json --docker-network localstack_default
```

And in your code, the LocalStack hostname should be `localstack_localstack_1`

```js
const dynamoDbDocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  endpoint: process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL ?
    'http://localstack_localstack_1:4569' :
    undefined,
});
```

However, I launched LocalStack using `docker-compose up`. Using the `pip` CLI tool to launch LocalStack may result in different identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for someone who are still facing the same issue:

I also faced the same problem recently. I followed all the steps mentioned by [rynop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563420/rynop) (Thanks @rynop)

I fixed the issue (on my windows) by replacing the endpoint (http://localhost:8000) with my (private) IP address (i.e http://192.168.8.101:8000) in the following code:

```
import { DynamoDB, Endpoint } from 'aws-sdk';

const ddb = new DynamoDB({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' });

if (process.env['AWS_SAM_LOCAL']) {
  ddb.endpoint = new Endpoint('http://dynamo:8000');
} else if ('local' == process.env['APP_STAGE']) {
  // Use this when running code directly via node. Much faster iterations than using sam local
  ddb.endpoint = new Endpoint('http://localhost:8000');
}
```