# Invoke Lambda Locally from Local Lambda

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose, docker-network, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to invoke a lambda function locally that invokes another lambda function, also local.

I am using `sam local start-lambda -t notificationServiceTemplate.yml --docker-network lambda-local --host 0.0.0.0`

I then start my consumer lambda, that invokes the worker lambda,

`aws lambda invoke --function-name ImportUsageConsumerLambda --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:3001`

The consumer lambda function makes the invoke call using these parameters,

```
if (process.env.STACK_ENVIRONMENT == "local" ) {
     options.endpoint = "http://0.0.0.0:3001/";
     options.sslEnabled = false;
 }
 lambda = new AWS.Lambda(options);
```

It doesn't work because the lambda container cannot access localhost in outside the container, `UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: '0.0.0.0\'. This service may not be available in the 'us-west-2\' region.\n`.

I understand using the endpoint `0.0.0.0:3001` will not work because that is where the `start-lambda` setups the lambda endpoint that is accessible to my host and not the same network as within the lambda docker container.

I've managed to get connected to a dynamodb docker container following this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926260/connecting-aws-sam-local-with-dynamodb-in-docker#49025379).

Is there a simple way to do this that I am missing?
Like a hostname of the lambda container that I can call from inside the lambda container, i.e. `options.endpoint = "http://lambda:3001/";`?

Comment: localhost is not 0.0.0.0, it's 127.0.0.1.  It's not clear why you are using 127.0.0.1 as the endpoint in one place but not the other.

Comment: Thanks, that is true. I was using 127.0.0.1 in all places, but in my vain attempts to connect the two I tried using host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score -1):

I have had some success using host.docker.internal:PORT for connecting my local lambda to my container running django.